# What's the literal definition of currency?

Tags: meaning, etymology

The word seems like it should mean a measure of how current something is, i.e. "*The currency of the year 2017 makes it more relevant than 3017.*"

The words seem to be in the same family.

Has currency been used so much over time, in regards to money, that it's lost its original meaning; or, am I mistaken?

Comment: In order to use the tag "single-word-requests", you have to request a single word for something. You have not.

Comment: Individual words have multiple meanings. Which one is intended depends on context. [Did you look up 'currency' in a dictionary?](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=currency) to see which definition really came first?

Comment: The sense of "currency" meaning "being current" is certainly valid and used with reasonable frequency.  One does need to use a bit of care with the word, though, to make sure that a use in the sense of "being current" isn't likely to be confused with the sense of "money".

Answer (score 1):

The original meaning of [currency](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=currency) is from that  of flowing, running, later extended to the concept of money "circulation", that is the movement, the flow of money:

> - 1650s, "condition of flowing," from Latin currens, present participle of currere 
>     "to run" ([see current (adj.](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=current&allowed_in_frame=0))); ***the sense of a flow or course extended 1699 (by John Locke) to "circulation of money."***

(Etymonline)

Comment: Maybe this etymology explains the use of words and phrases such as [liquidity](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/liquidity) and *liquid assets* or *cash flow* and of course *currency* when talking about money and exchange of money through purchasing and selling